# cauchy's theorem for nonabelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Can we use Cauchy's thm. for nonabelian groups indirectly? Say |G|=2p where p is a prime greater than 2. G is also not cyclic. How do you show G contains at least one element of order p and at least one element of order 2.

I was able to show the first part. The second asks to use part 1 to show that G contains a normal subgroup of order p. Can we say that G is abelian now? Or was that just a specific case from 1? A normal subgroup doesn't mean that the group is abelian, so would we use a similar argument?

Comment: I've rolled back to the original version; please do not vandalize your posts like that. If you want to ask questions about math.stackexchange itself, use [the meta site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

First all elements have order either 1, 2, p or 2p.

If there is an element of order 2p, the group is cyclic, not possible.

If all elements have order 1 or 2, the group is abelian, not possible. Therefore, there is an element of order $p$.

Finally if there is no element of order 2, pick some $x \in G$ and some $y \in G \backslash <x>$. Show that there are $2p-1$ elements in $<x> \cup <y>$.

Pick the remaining element $z$, then 
$$z^{-1} \in <x> \cup <y> \cup \{ z \}$$

But this is not compatible with all elements having order 1 or p.